# Retaining and releasing an object to a delegate

Tags: ios, memory-management, delegates

I'm developing an iOS 4 app with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I have a question about delegates and how to assign/release objects to them.

My code is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SBJson.h"
#import "WebServiceDelegate.h"

@interface UserWebService : NSObject
{
    SBJsonParser* parser;
    NSURLRequest* request;
    NSMutableData* receivedData;
    NSInteger response;

    id<WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger response;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)del;
```

And its implementation:

```
#import "UserWebService.h"

@implementation UserWebService

@synthesize response;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)del
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        delegate = [del retain];
        parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [parser release];
    [request release];
    [receivedData release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Is this correct?

```
delegate = [del retain];
```

And, Have I to release `del` at dealloc?

If I use

```
delegate = del;
```

instead of

```
delegate = [del retain];
```

I get a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** on object dealloc.

In a nutshell, I'm not sure if I'm assign and releasing `del` object correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using delegates, your object should not retain & release it since it does not own it.

> Implement the accessor methods. In a memory-managed program, to avoid
>   retain cycles, the setter method should not retain or copy your
>   delegate.

```
- (id)delegate {
    return delegate;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate {
    delegate = newDelegate;
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html)

Comment: This is correct, it is also worth mentioning that it is usually assumed that the delegate outlives the object it is a delegate of, or this pattern breaks down.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. I get an error if I don't retain del.

Comment: Are you sure you're not releasing the delegate object before the `UserWebService` object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the delegate value like this

```
@interface UserWebService : NSObject
{
    SBJsonParser* parser;
    NSURLRequest* request;
    NSMutableData* receivedData;
    NSInteger response;

    id<WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger response;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)del;

@implementation UserWebService

@synthesize response;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)del
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
         delegate = del;
        parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So in that case you do not need to release the delegate

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. I get an error if I don't retain del.

Comment: Do not release the delegate in dealloc.
If you are assigning any object then you don't need to release it.

Comment: No, I'm not releasing delegate in dealloc.

Comment: I think I'm having a problem when I try to release a released object. Debugging I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I'm releasing `[parser release]` (this object was released on `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` method.

Comment: Ok, If you release any object then you get that error message.